# Show an alert if route guards don't give you access

Tags: angular

I'm using a Route Guard which doesn't give access to a page unless the user is logged in. But I also want to show a message to the user that he has to log in first. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
class OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard implements CanActivate { 
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}; 

  canActivate() {
    console.log("OnlyLoggedInUsers");
    if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) { 
      return true;
    } else {
      window.alert("You don't have permission to view this page"); 
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

And:

```
{
  path: 'artist/:artistId',
  component: ArtistComponent,
  canActivate: [OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard, AlwaysAuthGuard], 
  children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'tracks'},
    {path: 'tracks', component: ArtistTrackListComponent},
    {path: 'albums', component: ArtistAlbumListComponent},
  ]
}
```